# Truncation Warning when data should fit

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are updating column A with the exact value from column B.  The length of column B is 255 and column A is 4.  The data in column B has been verified by LEN(REVERSE(colB)) to be only 4.  When we try to update the error message says:

```
'String or binary data would be truncated.'
```

here is the query:

```
update table 
set columnA=columnB  
where Column B in ('ABC','ABCD','AB')
```

we have also verified that this works:

```
update table 
set columnA=left(columnB,4)  
where Column B in ('ABC','ABCD','AB')
```

any guesses as to what could be wrong?
thanks

Comment: That's obvious .. with `columnA=columnB` you are trying to set columnb value entirely to columna which is why the error. You second query is doing the correct by cutting only 4 characters. BTW, your `WHERE` condition will never be true since `columnB` will not match those provided values.

Comment: Did you try to cast column B as varchar(4)?

Comment: Does the second query (LEFT(4)) give the error message as well?

Comment: @ruslan the second query does not give an error

Comment: Trailing spaces aren't counted by `len` or taken into account for string comparisons.

Comment: @rahul the fields are Varchar,  so it should not cause an error.

Comment: @MartinSmith the fields have been left and right trimmed

Comment: And have you ran a basic `select * from table where len(columnB) > 4`?

Comment: Is that message really an error, or is it just a warning? Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server, MySQL, DB2, etc.)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' This is SQL Server, and it is a warning

Comment: @Ruslan I have run  select * from table where len(columnB) > 4 and it returned no rows

Comment: In that case, I'd disregard it. If you run the update, and then compare all the rows and they are equal, it might be ok to ignore it. It's probably trailing spaces or line breaks somewhere.

Comment: So either this is coming from a trigger (seems unlikely as the update with `left` succeeds) or the strings haven't been right trimmed.

Comment: What does `select * from table where datalength(columnB) > 4` return?

Comment: @MartinSmith select * from table where datalength(columnB) > 4 returns no rows

Comment: Any triggers, persisted computed columns or indexed views that reference the table?

Comment: @MartinSmith no triggers persisted computed columns or indexed views

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This query works And I am ok with it.

update table 
set columnA=columnB
where Column B in ('ABC','ABCD','AB') and len(columnb)<=4

I am still curious as to why

Comment: Why: Because the engine looks at the field size defined on the table for these two fields, NOT the data itself.  By specifing a length restriction it overrides the analysis of just the two fields in the two tables.  If you specify <=5 you'd likely still get the error because columnA is only 4 characters...

Comment: and it's likely a warning.. .not an ERROR. indicating data MAY have been truncated...

Comment: @xQbert not likely at all as SQL Server doesn't return any warnings in that instance. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are using a `char` (not `varchar`) data type for column B, in which case your database engine may consider the width of the column, regardless of the width of the data. A `trim` function may then get rid of the error.

Comment: fields are both Varchar

Answer (score -1):

SQL doesn't check the actual length of the string - it just detects that the string value COULD overflow the new container and gives you an error message.  Try this:

update table set ColumnA=(select LEFT(ColumnB, 4) from table where ColumnB in ('ABC', 'ABCD', 'AB'));

This selects only the first four characters of the data from columnB.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't give warnings that a string could overflow in this context. You only see that type of warning in some DDL (such as creating an index where keys might be > 900 bytes) This is an actual error message.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I asked. FWIW, OP says in comments that it's a warning, not an error.

Comment: @mike yes I saw that but they are wrong. The update will have failed. The severity of this message is error not warning.

Comment: I created a test table, reproduced his error, and then got it to work with this solution.  And the poster confirmed that it worked FTR.